# Self-defined class error: incomplete type and can't be defined

Tags: c++, class

I want to defined a class Add to store Big Integer and calculate its summation , but there is error when I tried to instantiation the class:

The error is :   *error: incomplete type and can't be defined*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Add;

int main()
{
    char text[102];
    Add sum;            //error?
    while(cin>>text)
    {
        if(text[0]=='0' && text[1]=='\0')
            break;
        Add num(text);  //error?
        sum+=num;
    }
    sum.display();
    return 0;
}

class Add           //Used to store and calculate big integer
{
    public:
        Add():text(NULL),numSize(0) { memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr)); }
        Add(char *t);
        Add& operator+=(Add& rhs);

        void display();
    private:
        char* text;
        int arr[110];
        int numSize;

        void toIntArr();
        void toCharArr();

};

Add::Add(char* t):text(t),numSize(0)
{
    memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr));
    toIntArr();
    while(t!='\0')
    {
        ++numSize;
        ++t;
    }

}

Add& Add::operator+=(Add& rhs)
{
    int carryBit=0;
    for(int i=0; i<numSize; ++i)
    {
        int sum=arr[i]+rhs.arr[i]+carryBit;         //可以访问私有成员？
        if(sum>=10)
        {
            arr[i]=sum/10;
            carryBit=sum%10;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i]=sum;
            carryBit=0;
        }
    }
    if(carryBit!=0)
        arr[numSize++]=carryBit;
    toCharArr();

    return *this;
}

void Add::toIntArr()
{
    for(int i=0; i<numSize; ++i)
        arr[numSize-i-1]=text[i]-'0';
}

void Add::toCharArr()
{
    for(int i=0; i<numSize; ++i)
        text[numSize-i-1]=arr[i]+'0';
    text[numSize]='\0';
}

void Add::display()
{
    for(int i=0; i<numSize; ++i)
        cout<<arr[i];
}
```

Comment: Forward declaration only allow you to use pointers to the forward declared class. The reason is that the compiler cannot know its size before it is fully defined.

Comment: In this case I see no need for a forward declaration. Just put the class definition before your main.

Comment: ...and btw dont use "using namespace std"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When can I use a forward declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the compiler instantiates an object it shall know the size of the object that to correctly allocate memory. Also the cmpiler need to know constructor declarations that to call the appropriate constructor.

In your program the class is only declared before  its using.

```
class Add;

int main()
{
    char text[102];
    Add sum;
    //...
```

So the compiler does not know how to create object `sum`. Place the class definition before its using in main.

Or place the class definition in a header and include this header in the module with main.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to "define" the class:

- Forward declaration. This shows the least information, it simply shows that the name defines a type (in particular a class). That is what you have done here at the top with the class Add.
- Definition. The class header with its methods. That is your section of code that begins `class Add` until the `};` that closes it.
- Implemetation of the class methods.

To be "complete", i.e to use a class and declare an instance of it, you need the second level, i.e. it needs to be "fully defined".

If it is only "forwardly declared" it is also called "incomplete". You can declare pointers or reference to it and pass them through functions.

In order to have a working program, the class needs to have a full definition, i.e. all its methods. If not it will break at link time.

Normally, you write code in different "compilation units" so `main()` would go in one, and the implementation of the methods of `Add` would go in another one, and you would use a header file to put in the definition of `Add`, so both compilation units can see it.

As `main` needs a full definition of `Add`, it needs to appear after it. An include will "pull in" the code of the header.

In your case, where it is written in one long file, it must appear after it, but the position of the class implementations and main() can appear in either order.

Answer (score -1):

The main func should be after all of the def and implement.

Comment: Maybe for this example it will work, but the politically correct answer is: The definition of the class and its implementation should be in separate files each and only the header included in the main.